# address function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying something out in html and I want to use the Metric prefixes like k, m, b and such... I found the code below which works splendidly but I don't know how to reference it in html.

I want to make it apply to this html code, instead of displaying: Ape cost: 1000000 I want it to display 1M.

The function works as intended just that I don't know how to use it while in HTML.

thx :)

```html
<img STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:5px; LEFT:200px;" src='http//:myImage.png' width='95' height='40' onmouseover="this.src=' http//:myImage2.png ';" onmouseout="http//:myImage3.png';" onclick="buyApe()" />


<p style="position: fixed; top: -10; left: 300px">Ape Cost: <span id="apeCost">10</span> 
  <br />Apes: <span id="ape">0</span>
</p>
```

```js
function nFormatter(num) {

  if (num >= 1000000000) {
    return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1) + 'G';
  }
  if (num >= 1000000) {
    return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1) + 'M';
  }
  if (num >= 1000) {
    return (num / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k';
  }
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your script block after the declaration of the nFormatter function and the html-elements.

```
var costDisplay = document.getElementById("apeCost");
var originalValue = parseInt(costDisplay.innerHTML);

costDisplay.innerHTML = nFormatter(originalValue);
```

What is this script doing:

I fetches your `apeCost` element by id using `document.getElementById`. With that function you can select any unique id from your html. Then we want to change it's contents via `innerHTML` and that's also the way of retrieving the contents. We `costDisplay.innerHTML` through `parseInt`. This makes us sure that the value we retrieve is an integer. Finally we pass it through `nFormatter` to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foo(a) {
  return a + 1;
}

var ape = document.getElementById('ape').firstChild.nodeValue;
document.getElementById('ape').firstChild.nodeValue = foo(ape);
```

```html
<img STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:5px; LEFT:200px;" src='http//:myImage.png' width='95' height='40' onmouseover="this.src=' http//:myImage2.png ';" onmouseout="http//:myImage3.png';" onclick="buyApe()" />


<p style="position: fixed; top: -10; left: 300px">Ape Cost: <span id="apeCost">10</span> 
  <br />Apes: <span id="ape">10000000</span>
</p>
```

You then replace `foo` with whatever function you need.